# jquery tooltip is not working on disabled checkbox

Tags: jquery

I want to show a tool-tip message on mouse over on disabled check box, but i am not able show the tool-tip message.

```
var sClass = 'chbx_'+ sAssesItemID;
if("0" == objItemSummary.skipStandard && $('.'+ sClass + ':checked').length == 1){
    if(!o.checked){
        $('#tdStandard'+ sAssesItemID +'___ > input.'+sClass+'').each(function(i, n){
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                //  $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled').css('cursor','pointer').attr('title', 'At least one standard must be selected for each item.'); // Added css Message as per task "IB Setup Summary Tab Remove Warning Message" since V4.1.0 By Mahananda
                $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $(this).addClass('enable-tooltip');
                $(this).attr('data-original-title','At least one standard must be selected for each item.').data('toggle', 'tooltip').data('trigger', 'hover').data('placement', 'right').data('html', 'true').data('toggle','model');
                $(this).data('toggle', 'tooltip').data('trigger', 'hover').data('placement', 'right').data('html', 'true').data('toggle','model');
                $('.enable-tooltip').tooltip();
            }
        });
    }else $('#' + o.id).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}else { 
    $('.'+ sClass).removeAttr('disabled');
    $('.'+ sClass).removeAttr('data-original-title');
}
```

Comment: Which plugin you use?

Comment: I think  that a disabled input won't ever register with jQuery, so you will need to fake it. Disabled inputs by the w3 spec are inactive, unusable, unclickable and I imagine unhoverable.

Comment: jquery tool tip i am using

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap the disabled button and put the tooltip on the wrapper:

Please check below working snippet.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.tooltip-wrapper').tooltip();
});
```

```css
.tooltip-wrapper {
  display: inline-block; /* display: block works as well */
  margin: 50px; /* make some space so the tooltip is visible */
}

.tooltip-wrapper input[disabled] {
  /* don't let button block mouse events from reaching wrapper */
  pointer-events: none;
}

.tooltip-wrapper.disabled {
  /* OPTIONAL pointer-events setting above blocks cursor setting, so set it here */
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="tooltip-wrapper disabled" title="Hey dude!!!!">
<input type="checkbox" disabled/>
</div>
```

Comment: i checked above code, it showing tool-tip message but not disabling checkbox.

Comment: You can disable checkbox by passing disabled property in checkbox as I have done in snippet.

Comment: yes i done like this $(this).addClass('disabled'); by replacing  $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

Comment: in default method i m calling like this

Comment: var sdisabled = (((1 == arrStdIDs.length || (1 == arrCheckedStdIDs.length && 'checked' == sChecked)) && ("0" == objItemSummary.skipStandard))) ? 'disabled' : '';, this sdisabled  i will pass in my html

Comment: shtml += '<input style="height:0.5em;width:0.5em;" class="' + sCls + '" type="checkbox" value="' + sSTDID + '" id="std_'+ objIS.assessmentItemID +'_'+ sSTDID + '" ' + sChecked + ' ' + sdisabled + ' onclick="javascript:stdToggleCheckbox(this, '+objIS.assessmentItemID+');" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="right" data-html="true" data-toggle="modal" title="" data-original-title="'+title+' '+$chID+'"></input><span>' + sFullNum + '</span>';

Comment: its allowing me to click on checkbox.

Comment: Why have you replaced $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled'); with $(this).addClass('disabled');?

Comment: To make your element disabled you have to set disabled attribute not disabled class.

Comment: thanks for your guidance, if i add $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled'); than tool tip is not showing.so i added addClass

Comment: If you will follow the steps which I have mentioned in the answer. You will able to add tooltip on the disabled element.

Comment: thanks it is working in default method but when check and uncheck the other checkboxes than this  logic is not working

Comment: i am banned to ask question as i asked poor question, can u please like my question so that i ask new question,please  :)

Comment: After wrapping the checkbox in div make sure the add display:inline css to div. This will give the tooltip on checkbox